# SQLWindows - How to check Line Number?

Tags: guptateamdeveloper

I am new to SQLWindows IDE and I need to edit a number of SQLWindows applications. I am using Version 3.0.0 of the IDE. I am facing trouble finding the line number of a particular line of code. Is there any setting or way to know the line number of the code? Generally IDEs provide the line number, but I am not able to see any line number details in the [Outline] mode. Kindly help!

Comment: I don't think any of the centura IDEs show a line number, the do not work that way. Why do you need the line number?

Comment: I need to make certain changes in few lines of code. Thought it would be helpful to have line numbers to locate the specific lines in the lengthy code every time I need to refer them in future. But nowhere, I could find any line number system as generally featured in other IDEs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLWindows doesn't use line numbers at all.

If you want to change similar code lines in several files, I suggest getting acquainted with the CDK, which lets you write applications that alter .app/apt/apl files. Unfortunately wasn't able to find a "Starter Guide" on Google.

Answer (score 1):

Im guessing you have corruption in a apl file ?  If so save the file as 'text' , ( never save as Binary i.e. 'Compiled' or 'App' always save using the 'Text' option ) then re-open it.  9 out of 10 any line number errors fix automatically this way .  Once you have saved as Text , you can open it and edit it ( carefully ) in Notepad++ .
Its very unusual to need to know a line number....why would you possibly want to know it ?  If you explain more , there may be a better workaround ( there always is )

Comment: I am working on an existing application that is too lengthy and complex. I need to make certain changes in mulitple lines of code. I thought it would be helpful to have line numbers to locate the specific lines that I need to work upon, so that every time I need to refer to them, I won't have to do ALT+F3 for a keyword search to locate the lines. But nowhere, I could find any line number system as generally featured in other IDEs.

Comment: Well in 7.0 and up (or maybe 6.X already) breakpoints are finally persistent, so a disabled one can be used as a bookmark of sorts. Still requires a manual lookup, so this would be a slightly more cumbersome variant to simply placing a comment with a keyword - the latter might even be used with automation outside of Centura: find the comment line, then alter the next line.